# Is there a way to write suspendable delegated property in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, delegates, coroutine, kotlin-coroutines

I was trying to implement something similar to [Process Variables](https://www-csr.bessy.de/control/SoftDist/sequencer/Tutorial.html) using special feature called `delegate` provided by kotlin.

Let's take following simple use case:

- I have two variables called `var voltage: Float` and `var light: Boolean`
- When `voltage` becomes greater than 5.0, I want to turn on light
- When `voltage` becomes less than 5.0, I want to turn off light

Note each variable change needs to publish changed value (involves network call)

Above use case is captured in following code snippet

```
    suspend fun publishLightStatus(status: Boolean): Unit = TODO()
    suspend fun publishVoltage(voltage: Float): Unit = TODO()

    fun subscribeToVoltage(block: (Float) -> Unit): Unit = TODO()

    var light: Boolean by Delegates.observable(false) { _, _, n ->
        publishLightStatus(n)
    }

    var voltage: Float by Delegates.observable(0F) { _, _, n ->
        if(n > 5.0) light = true
        else if (n < 5.0) light = false

        publishVoltage(n)
    }

    // usage
    subscribeToVoltage {
        voltage = it
    }
```

Above code does not compile because currently `property delegates` does not support suspensions.
`getValue` and `setValue` function from `ReadWriteProperty` are not suspendable.
Also `suspend operator getValue()` syntax is not supported.

**Is there a way I can get around with this?**
I really do not want to compromise with usage site code.
Another important thing, `voltage = it` this should return when `publishVoltage(n)` call finished.

Answer (score 4):

In general properties should be simple and should return quickly. They shouldn't be exposing anything to warrant suspension but that's only an opinion.

There's no way to do this right now but there's a YouTrack issue [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-20414) and [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-15555) concerning this.

You could also try using `runBlocking` or `GlobalScope.launch` which might suit your needs.